# Retrieving values from dynamically created controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, basic

First post, so go easy on me.

I've been coding for years, first with VB6, then VB.NET and more recently ASP.NET.  I'm ashamed to say, this issue has beaten me to the point where I need to ask for help.  What's more annoying is that this should be a simple thing to achieve!  I'm clearly missing something here.

I'm creating checkbox controls dynamically, quite a few of them in fact.  Two per dynamically created table row and their IDs are appended with the ID of the particular DB record on the row, row 1, 2, 3 etc.  So on each row there would be two checkboxes, ihave_check_1, ineed_check_1.  The next row would be ihave_check_2 and ineed_check_2 and so on.

There is a submit button at the bottom of the page, and when clicked, it's supposed to loop through each row (and cell) in the table and pick out controls whose IDs contain "ihave_check_" and "ineed_check_" then get their Checked value.  Once I have the values, I add a record into the database.

Problem is, when you click the button, the table disappears and so do the values.

From what I've read so far, this is happening because the controls are dynamically created, if they were static (coded in the HTML section) I wouldn't have this problem.

So first question, what do I need to do to get it working?
And second question, why is using dynamic controls so difficult?

Here's the code setting up the table, which works great:

```
Private Sub ddCardSeries_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddCardSeries.SelectedIndexChanged
    If IsPostBack = True And Not ddCardSeries.SelectedValue = "Select..." Then
        cardsTable.Visible = True
        Dim dat As New DataLayer3.DataConnector
        dat.DataConnector("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=192.XXX.XXX.XXX;Database=GPKDB;User Id=sa;Password=XXXXXXXXXXX;")
        Dim dtSections As New DataTable
        dtSections = dat.DataSelect("SELECT baseCardID,baseCardSeries,baseCardNumber,baseCardName,frontArtist,conceptArtist,backArtist,backWriter,isBaseCard,isDieCut,isMatte,isGlossy,differentBack,frontImage,backImage FROM baseCards where baseCardSeries = '" & Split(Split(ddCardSeries.Text, "(ID:")(1), ")")(0) & "' and isBaseCard = 'Yes'")
        If dtSections.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To dtSections.Rows.Count - 1

                Dim row As New TableRow
                For x = 0 To dtSections.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim cell1 As New TableCell
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtSections.Rows(i)(x)) Then
                        If x = 0 Then
                            cell1.Text = dtSections.Rows(i)(x)
                        ElseIf x = 1 Then
                            cell1.Text = get_card_series(dtSections.Rows(i)(x))
                        ElseIf x = 13 Then
                            cell1.Text = "<img src='" & dtSections.Rows(i)(x) & "' height='120'"
                        ElseIf x = 14 Then
                            cell1.Text = "<img src='" & dtSections.Rows(i)(x) & "' height='120'"
                        Else
                            cell1.Text = dtSections.Rows(i)(x)
                        End If

                    Else
                        cell1.Text = ""
                    End If
                    row.Cells.Add(cell1)


                Next x
                Dim newbutton As New Button
                Dim newlabel As New Label
                newlabel.Text = "<br />"
                newbutton.Text = "Modify this entry"
                newbutton.Width = 120
                newbutton.ID = "modify_button_" & dtSections.Rows(i)(0)
                Dim newcheck1 As New CheckBox
                Dim newlabel2 As New Label
                newlabel2.Text = "<br />"
                newcheck1.Text = "I own this card"
                newcheck1.Width = 120
                newcheck1.ID = "ihave_check_" & dtSections.Rows(i)(0)
                Dim newcheck2 As New CheckBox
                newcheck2.Text = "I need this card"
                newcheck2.Width = 120
                newcheck2.ID = "ineed_check_" & dtSections.Rows(i)(0)
                Dim cell2 As New TableCell
                If is_user_admin() = True Then
                    newbutton.Enabled = True
                Else
                    newbutton.Enabled = False
                End If

                cell2.Controls.Add(newbutton)
                cell2.Controls.Add(newlabel)
                cell2.Controls.Add(newcheck1)
                cell2.Controls.Add(newlabel2)
                cell2.Controls.Add(newcheck2)
                row.Cells.Add(cell2)



                cardsTable.Rows.Add(row)
            Next
        End If

    Else
        cardsTable.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the code that loops through the table and tries to save the results to the database:

```
    Protected Sub SubmitChanges_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitChanges.Click

    For Each pcontrol As control In Page.Controls
        Dim havecard As String = Nothing
        Dim needcard As String = Nothing
        Dim rowcardid As String = Nothing
        'For Each tabcell As TableCell In tabrow.Cells
        'For Each pgcontrol As Control In tabcell.Controls
        If TypeOf pcontrol Is CheckBox And Split(pcontrol.ID, "_")(0) = "ihave" Then
            rowcardid = Split(pcontrol.ID, "_")(2)
            Dim chkbox As CheckBox = pcontrol
            If chkbox.Checked = True Then
                havecard = "Yes"
            Else
                havecard = "No"
            End If
        End If
        If TypeOf pcontrol Is CheckBox And Split(pcontrol.ID, "_")(0) = "ineed" Then
            rowcardid = Split(pcontrol.ID, "_")(2)
            Dim chkbox As CheckBox = pcontrol
            If chkbox.Checked = True Then
                needcard = "Yes"
            Else
                needcard = "No"
            End If
        End If
        'Next

        If Not havecard = Nothing And Not needcard = Nothing Then
            If add_card_to_user_list(Session("username"), rowcardid, havecard, needcard) = True Then
                Label1.Text = "Update complete"
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Update failed"
            End If
        End If


        'Next
    Next




End Sub



Public Function add_card_to_user_list(ByVal userid As String, ByVal cardid As String, ByVal own As String, ByVal need As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim dat As New DataLayer3.DataConnector
        dat.DataConnector("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=192.XXX.XXX.XXX;Database=GPKDB;User Id=sa;Password=XXXXXXXX;")
        Dim dtCardSeries As New DataTable
        dtCardSeries = dat.DataSelect("select CardID from [" & userid & "_cards] where cardid = '" & cardid & "'")
        If dtCardSeries.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            dat.DataDelete("delete from [" & userid & "_cards] where cardid = '" & cardid & "'")
        End If
        dat.DataInsert("insert into [" & userid & "_cards] (Username,CardID,Own,Need) values ('" & userid & "', '" & cardid & "', '" & own & "', '" & need & "');")
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try



End Function
```

Any help at this point would be gratefully received.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're dynamically building out the table in the ````ddCardSeries_SelectedIndexChanged```` event, but when you do the button click and the page post backs, that event is not getting ran.  You need to move that code into a function like ````BindData()```` -- you can call that function in the dropdown change event, but you can also call it on PostBacks in the Page_Load function.

Comment: You may want to look into AndAlso. Won't solve your problem but it short circuits your If statements and saves a nano second. :-)

Comment: Can you use the more up to date SqlClient instead of SQLOLE?